# Jar file opens with internet explorer

Tags: windows-10, java, internet-explorer, minecraft, jar

I downloaded Optifine, it's a jar file, after that i installed Java to install optifine with the jar file, but the jar file opens with internet Explorer prompting me to download the file again. This is häppening with Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.jar` file-association has probably been hijacked, perhaps by Internet Explorer.

You can fix the problem with:

- Download and run the free
  [Jarfix](https://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html), or
- Uninstalling an then re-installing Java Runtime, or
- In Windows Explorer, right-click on the `.jar` file, select *Open with*
  and click on *Choose another app*. Navigate to and select `javaw.exe`.
  You would need to ensure a `-jar` parameter is added.

It would be better to add the JRE executable folder to the PATH environment variable,
although not absolutely required.

Comment: Jarfix worked great, thank you

Comment: it would help if you could add how/where someone adds the -jar parameter, or how one adds it if it wasn't added when first selected

Answer (score -1):

Right Click on it -> Open with and then select the Java Runtime Enviroment. Also make sure ypu have Java installed. If its not in this list, search for it in your program files folder. 
Viele Grüße!

Comment: it is not in the folder program files, i checked "program files (x86)" the folder java is there, i went there, then went to the folder "bin" there are different .exe's all starting with java, but none of them work

Comment: Weird. It should be java.exe

Comment: For me its in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe

Comment: i have the file, but it doesn't work when i open with it